# images disappearing from recyclerview when scroll back to top and some are not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview to show images, the problem is when I scroll back to top some images disappear. Sometimes it loads missing some images too...

CARDADAPTER:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private final Context context;

    //List to store all posts
    List<Posts> Posts;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<Posts> Post, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all
        this.Posts = Post;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        Posts post =  Posts.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Posts.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewName.setClickable(true);
            textViewName.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent;
            intent =  new Intent(context, Profile.class);
            intent.putExtra("user", textViewName.getText().toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

why my images disappear from recyclerview? what should I do?

Comment: Try with some dummy image and just `ImageView`instead of `NetworkImageView` - that case you will specify if problem related to `NetworkImageView`

Comment: thank you for your answer, to make this work should I only change `NetworkImageView` to `ImageView`? because it shows me an error: cannot find symbol method setImageUrl @Divers

Comment: No. As I said you should set dummy image on your `ImageView`.

Comment: Instead of creating the same question, better do what I suggested.

Comment: sorry, I'm new on android studio. I'm a PHP developer learn things here. So I don't understand what is to `set dummy image on your ImageView` it is about my xml? could you explain what should I do? what file should I change? @Divers

Comment: Replace `NetworkImageView` with `ImageView` and set any **LOCAL** image to it, instead of downloading image remotely with `NetworkImageView`. Im on 99% sure that problem with `NetworkImageView`

Comment: @Divers thank you, I'm going to try it